Do global augmentations need to be imported as a side effect in the consumer?
I have a package called core.error. In this package I have two files
global.d.ts
export {};

declare global {
  export interface Error {
    foo(): void;
  }
}

index.ts
Error.prototype.foo = function (this: Error): void {
 
};

export const dooFoo = (err:Error) : void => {
  err.foo();
}

Now I have this package as a dependency in my second project. It seems the global augmentation code only gets executed up when I do this.
import "core.error"

const err = new Error();
err.foo();

But when I try to import the dooFoo function only i will get a runtme TypeError saying "TypeError: err.foo is not a function".
import { dooFoo } from "core.error"

const err = new Error();
err.foo();

Is this expected behaviour? If so do I need to import twice from my module like this?
import "core.error"
import { dooFoo } from "core.error"

const err = new Error();
dooFoo(err.foo());

Is there any other solution to properly load and run my module code that monkeypatches globals?
Update
Readings done before asking

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3290-using-module-augmentation-to-safely-inject-runtime-methods-using-typescript-and-node-js.htm
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only
How do you add polyfills to Globals in typescript (modules)

Update 2
The declaration file for index.ts looks like this
/// <reference types="node" />
export declare const dooFoo : (error: Error ) => void;

tsconfig.json looks like this
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2022",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "./build"
  },
  "include": ["source"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tests", "build"]
}


Turn on --verbatimModuleSyntax as described here. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

I will need to try it out

@jcalz That shouldn't make a difference, the import isn't elided as foo is a value.

"i will get a TypeError saying TypeError: err.foo is not a function" - do you mean a TypeScript compiler warning, or a runtime TypeError exception?

It's a runtime error. It only works if i do the import with side effects like this import "core.error"

@Jay Ah ok I was thrown off by "module augmentation" (which is a TypeScript term) and "gets picked up" (which I thought as "…by the typechecker"). I've edited to clarify - please rollback if you don't like the changes

This is weird given you still import doFoo from the module. Are you using a bundler or something that aggressively removes "unused" code? What does the compiled JS output look like?

My tsconfig looks like this
{   "compilerOptions": {     "module": "ES2022",     "target": "ES2022",     "allowJs": true,     "esModuleInterop": true,     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     "moduleResolution": "Bundler",     "resolveJsonModule": true,     "strict": true,     "outDir": "./build"   },   "include": ["source"],   "exclude": ["node_modules", "tests", "build"] } 

Have you had a chance to try the compiler setting I suggested? TS will often elide import statements without it.

@jcalz I can not change this setting because it is a company wide config

??? That doesn’t change the fact that it causes your problem. If you are unable to change compiler settings to fix compiler problems, then what could possibly be done here? And if you have such a restriction it should be [edit]ed into the question.

I would expect if this is the requirement to make this work that it would be properly mentioned somewhere in the docs. I could not find anything about this setting when doing research regarding this topic.

@Jay Even if there are organisational restrictions with applying this solution, you still should at least try out the suggested change in tsconfig to see whether it would solve the problem. If it works, we have at least correctly identified the problem, you then can a) still ask for alternative solutions b) try to lift your organisational restrictions

@Bergi verbatimModuleSyntax works but it breaks the complete build. I would need to rewrite all imports doing type imports. So still global augmentations have been there before TS 5.0 and i would be curious about an alternative solution not using this. The most common solution i have seen is to have a file with the side effects ( extending prototypes ) and import this file like import "mylib/sideffects.js".

TypeScript will elide imports that it (correctly or incorrectly) detects as being unused in the importing module. That means when it compiles to JavaScript, the import statement will be completely absent.
In your example you import dooFoo but never use it. And so Typescript thinks the import is useless and removes it. But TypeScript doesn't keep track of whether or not an imported module has side effects. So the elided import leads to the runtime error you're seeing.

The currently recommended approach is to use the --verbatimModuleSyntax compiler option as released with TypeScript 5.0 and implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#52203. This essentially turns off import elision (with the exception of imports that use the type modifier where the developer is explicitly asking for import elision).  Before TypeScript 5.0 there were other compiler options you could use to get this effect but they are no longer relevant and have been deprecated.
If you turn on --verbatimModuleSyntax then your dooFoo import is present in the compiled JavaScript and you get the desired side effect behavior.
Stackblitz link to code

If you can't use this approach then you'll need to work around it. One way is, as mentioned in the question, to explicitly write import "core.error" to perform a side-effect-only import, which TypeScript understands as having side effects.
Another way would be to leave the import alone but actually use dooFoo in your code so that TypeScript doesn't think it can elide anything:
import { dooFoo } from "core.error"
dooFoo; // <-- mention it somewhere    
const err = new Error();
err.foo();

Stackblitz link to code
This last way is probably the most normal alternative approach, since presumably you're going to actually use an imported function somewhere in your code.
But I'd recommend using --verbatimModuleSyntax since it makes TypeScript behave more consistently, and only get elision when you explicitly ask for it with an import type statement.
